# Driving a 125 ccm motorcycle in Spain with EU licence

Tags: driving, spain, driving-licenses, motorcycles

In Spain they allow drivers holding a Spanish B licence (for cars) to drive 125 ccm motorcycles without further training or applying for a licence.

So, once you have the B, even if it does not estipulate in it that you can drive small motorcycles, you are allowed to.

Does this rule also apply to me, driving with a Belgian EU permit B? Is there any official source confirming or denying this?

Comment: Strange, cm really? Do you mean cc?

Comment: @Itai In reality, it's cm3, and there are 2 non-SI abbreviations: cc and ccm, which mean the same. But this is also not that important, because it's about not exceding the  power of 11kW or 15HP

Comment: In many countries, you get authomatically A1 when you get B licence. Do you have A1 in your driving licence? EU driving licences are now standarized AFAIK, so you should have all categories listed on the rear side, with validity date for categories you have...

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, it is allowed to move vehicles of the category [A1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_driving_licence)(!) in Spain if your license which allows you to drive B is at least 3 years old.**

Quotation from Wikipedia:

> B licence holders in Czech Republic (only motorcycles with automatic transmission), Italy, Latvia, Malta (after a training of 10 hours), Slovakia (after two years and only motorcycles with automatic transmission), **Spain (after three years)**, Poland (after three years), Portugal (at least 25 years old or additional licence for mopeds), and Belgium (only with a Belgian Driving Licence, after two years) are allowed to drive motorcycles not exceeding 125 cubic centimetres (7.6 cu in) within the respective countries. In Austria (after five years, training of 6 hours), France (after two years, a training of 7 hours), Luxembourg (after two years, training of 7 hours), and the United Kingdom (Compulsory Basic Training), a practical training without exam is needed for B licence holders.

German source: http://motorrad.wikia.com/wiki/Ausland

*Wer den Führerschein Klasse B mindestens 3 Jahre hat, darf automatisch auch 125er fahren. Das gilt auch für Ausländer.* Translation: Who has an EU license which is at least 3 years old, is allowed to drive 125ccm motorcycles. This also applies to foreigners.